# Create multidimentional JSon array from multiple tables

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a json array with a structure like this:

```
var cars = [
    {name: 'Honda', models: [
        {name: 'Accord', features: ['2dr', '4dr']},
        {name: 'CRV', features: ['2dr', 'Hatchback']},
        {name: 'Pilot', features: ['base', 'superDuper']}
    ]},
    {name: 'Toyota', models: [
        {name: 'Prius', features: ['green', 'superGreen']},
        {name: 'Camry', features: ['sporty', 'square']},
        {name: 'Corolla', features: ['cheap', 'superFly']}
    ]}
];
```

From 3 tables (`carmakes`, `carmake_models` and `carmake_options`) in my MySQL database.
What is the best way to go about it?

The tables are structured as follows:

> **carmakes:** ID, CarName
>   **carmake_models:** ModelParent, ModelName
>   **carmake_options:** OptionParent, OptionName

Comment: What format are your tables in?

Comment: The tables are structured like:


carmakes: ID, CarName
carmake_models: ModelParrent, ModelName
carmake_options: ModelParrent, OptionName

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough information to answer your question. However, you might do better to create JSON more like this:

```
var cars = {
    'Honda': {
        'Accord':  ['2dr', '4dr'],
        'CRV':     ['2dr', 'Hatchback'],
        'Pilot':   ['base', 'superDuper']
    },
    'Toyota': {
        'Prius':   ['green', 'superGreen'],
        'Camry':   ['sporty', 'square'],
        'Corolla': ['cheap', 'superFly']
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, the question was not the structure of the JSon, but how to create the PHP output/array and then convert it to the before mentioned JSon structure for use in my application... I am a bit lost here...